# Populated DropDownList using SqlDataSource,how to rename list items? Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have populated dropdownlist using SQLDataSource, and everything works fine. I have set to  display column that has boolean type of value, so in my drop down list items are False,True. Is there any way to rename those items. For example false to be "Sold" and True"In stock"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modifed.

Comment: I dont have code for that, i have uses SQLDataSource wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in the SQL Select Command using a Case statements, Where 'Sold' is the column as Boolean.

```
 SELECT Sold, CASE WHEN Sold=1 THEN 'In Stock' ELSE 'Sold Out' END AS SoldLbl 
     FROM SomeTable ....
```

Then in the dropdown bind ,make the Value = 'Sold' and the Label = 'SoldLbl' from the SQLdatasource.

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper class to hold your data objects.

```
public class ItemStatus
{
    private bool inStock;

    public Item(bool inStock)
    {
        this.inStock = inStock;
    }

    public string Value 
    { 
        get { return inStock ? "In Stock" : "Sold Out"; }
    }
}
```

Then create a `List<ItemStatus>()` and bind your dropdownlist datasource to this instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I will try. Is there way to do that in sql query?

Comment: I've never used a SQLDataSource, but if you're just reading data from a query using a SqlCommand and a SqlDataReader, you can create the list of objects using the reader.  There will be examples on MSDN of how to read a "SELECT * FROM Product" query into a List<Product>();